# Получение прав root

Tags: linux, пароль, root

Как получить права `root` в CentOS 6.6, если пароль `root` не был задан при установке (система не требовала) на виртуальную машину WMVare?

Не помогает `sudo` или `su` - требует пароль `root` или мой, при вводе которого сообщается, что меня нет в файле *sudoers*.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

1. Нужно загрузится в **single** режим, для этого пускаем систему в ребут, на момент выбора ядра ос (загрузщик **GRUB**) нажимаем кнопку "E", после чего откроется окно в котором будут написаны параметры загрузки, Вам нужно в конце строки с параметрами дописать **single** или **s**. После редактирования нажимаем Enter, а потом кнопку "b" для загрузки.
2. После загрузки будет открыт термиал, вводим команду `passwd root` , дальше задаем новый пароль для рута.
3. Перезагружаемся, все готово

Answer (score 4):

если при установке не предлагалось ввести пароль для пользователя *root*, то созданный во время установки первый пользователь, как правило, включается в группу `sudo` или `wheel` (в разных дистрибутивах по-разному), которая, как правило, присутствует в файле `/etc/sudoers`.

поэтому этот пользователь может использовать программу `sudo` (и различные «обёртки» вокруг неё, типа *gksudo*, *kdesudo* и т.п.), подтвердив (при запросе) полномочия вводом *своего* пароля.

но если уже после установки был, например, утерян пароль этого первого пользователя, или он был исключён из этой группы, или вносились изменения в `/etc/sudoers` по поводу группы `sudo/wheel`, то следует:

1. загрузиться в *single-режим*, добавив к параметрам ядра (через пробел) букву `s`.

   в разных дистрибутивах/версиях это может быть сделано по-разному, но обычно встречаются лишь два глобальных варианта:

   а) строка параметров ядра отображается сразу (или предлагается нажать какую-нибудь <kbd>f-клавишу</kbd> для её редактирования). после добавления (через пробел) `s` обычно достаточно нажать <kbd>enter</kbd> (но могут быть варианты: читайте подсказку на экране);

   б) с помощью кнопки (обычно <kbd>e</kbd>, но могут быть варианты: читайте подсказку на экране) отредактировать *параметры загрузки*. там будет много строк, надо найти строку(-и), начинающуюся со слова `linux` — это и будут параметры ядра, к которым и надо дописать (через пробел) `s` (если таких строк больше одной — на всякий случай исправьте их все). продолжить загрузку можно обычно клавишей <kbd>f10</kbd> или <kbd>b</kbd>, но могут быть варианты: читайте подсказку на экране.

   после загрузки вы попадёте в *root-овую* консоль, где можно вводить команды от имени *root*.
2. сначала надо перемонтировать корневую файловую систему в режим чтения-записи такой командой:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
3. затем сменить пароль пользователя *root* командой

   ```
   passwd root
   ```

   (старый пароль при этом не будет запрошен).
4. затем сбросить дисковый кэш на диск командой

   ```
   sync
   ```
5. теперь можно перезагружать компьютер клавишами <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> (или кнопкой *reset* или кнопкой питания).