# Модуль политики archlinux

Tags: sudo

```
sudo: не удаётся инициализировать модуль политики archlinux
```

На что выполнил все указания **ArchWiki** - (статья Sudo) - однако, политика не изменилась.
Вопрос: возможно, что что причиной всему является невеная настройка хоста?
так как он случайно совпадает с **onet.pl** ???
        Если нет, так в чем тогда причина?

Все выглядит примерно так:

```
[ivanov@localhost-onet ~]$ sudo pacman -Syy
>>> /etc/sudoers: ошибка синтаксиса near line 78 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 78
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: не удаётся инициализировать модуль политики
[ivanov@localhost-onet ~]$ sudo pacman -Syu
>>> /etc/sudoers: ошибка синтаксиса near line 78 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 78
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: не удаётся инициализировать модуль политики
[ivanov@localhost-onet ~]$ sudo pacman -S leafpad
>>> /etc/sudoers: ошибка синтаксиса near line 78 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 78
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: не удаётся инициализировать модуль политики
[ivanov@localhost-onet ~]$ yaourt -S opera

Пароль: 
su: Сбой при проверке подлинности
Пароль: 
su: Сбой при проверке подлинности
Пароль:
```

Comment: А что у вас написано в 78 строке /etc/sudoers и около нее, на которую оно собственно у ругается

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

в файле `/etc/sudoers` допущена синтаксическая ошибка в строке 78.

поэтому исполнение команд/программ от имени другого пользователя с помощью программы `sudo` не получится — до исправления этой ошибки.

чтобы избежать повторения такой ситуации в будущем, лучше не редактировать файл `/etc/sudoers` напрямую, а использовать программу `visudo`, которая перед перезаписью этого файла выполнит проверку его синтаксиса, и, если синтаксис нарушен, предложит исправить ошибку либо вообще отменить изменения.

---

если вам известен пароль пользователя *root*, вы можете запусить команду:

```
$ su -c visudo
```

и исправить строку с ошибкой.

---

если пароль пользователя *root* вам неизвестен, можете воспользоваться ответом на этот вопрос: [Получение прав root](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432479/178576)