# su operation not permitted

Tags: linux, su

Я ввел какую-то команду и она «сбила» права.

Я их восстановил, работает почти все что нужно, только я не могу запустить оболочку от имени пользователя root.

Команды могу выполнять через sudo.

вот вывод:

```
$ ls -l /bin/su
-rwsr-xr-x 1 jashka jashka 41072 июля  15  2015 /bin/su
$ su
Пароль:
setgid: Операция не позволена
```

Comment: вставляйте, пожалуйста, текстовую информацию в виде текста, а не картинки.

Answer (score 2):

файл `/bin/su` должен принадлежать пользователю *root* и группе *root*.

если вам доступно выполнение команд с использование *sudo*, то исправьте:

```
$ sudo chown root:root /bin/su
```

если не доступно, воспользуйтесь ответами к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/432479/178576) для загрузки в *single-режим* и после перемонтирования файловой системы в режим чтения-записи выполните команду:

```
# chown root:root /bin/su
```

Answer (score 1):

пользователю нужны привилегии для выполнения административных команд (например, пользователь должен принадлежать группам **adm** и **users**).

еще вариант: **загрузив** в систему в **однопользвательском режиме (single user mode, runlevel 1)**, использовать команду

`chmod u+s /bin/su`.

P.S.: использования sudo, как правило, хватает (например, если работаете в Ubuntu).