# Создать нового пользователя Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Система досталась в наследство.
Был запароленный пользователь, доступы к которому не узнать.  В итоге зашел как гость, попытался создать нового пользователя под себя (ведь прав на команды из Терминала просто не хватало), но:

> sudo: unable to change to root gid: Операция не позволена

Что делать?

Comment: другой дубль: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432487/178576

Answer (score 0):

так как это убунта, там нет рутового пароля, то нужно зайти в сингл моде. Вот прямо в картинках http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword