# Centos сброс пароля root (permission denied)

Tags: centos, root, password

Неоднократно сбрасывал пароль рута, но тут столкнулся с непобедимой проблемой -  фс в режиме readonly. Пробовал в грабе с параметром rw грузить в /bin/bash и перемонтировал корневой каталог с правами на чтение-запись. Результат один. Как вылечить? Попытки приложил скринами
[image: параметры grub]

[image: попытка1]

[image: попытка2]

Comment: вывод `mount` после перемонтирования глянь — может что-то пошло не так?

Comment: просто чётко следуйте инструкции, без самодеятельности. например, этой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432487/178576