# Как удалить пароль админа на Ubuntu или как удалить Linux и установить Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, пароль, root

Отдали комп с офиса, комп оказался для меня с сюрпризом, там стоял Linux (UBUNTU 2.14) да ещё и с  паролем администратора.
 Пробовали получить доступ сбросом пароля через recovery mode, но ничего не получилось, через grub тоже ничего не получилось
на компьютере 1 операционная система Ubuntu 2.14

При входе в gnu grub пишет:

```
ubuntu, with linux  3.4.0-23-generic
ubuntu, with linux  3.4.0-23-generic (recovery mode)
memory test (memtest86+)
memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
```

Когда открываешь `setparams` в `ubuntu, with linux  3.4.0-23-generic` клавишей `E` пишет:

```
recordfail
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1) '
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ebed8de5-5b3c-42f2-b540-c03708ddd21b
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=uuid=ebed8de5-5b3c-42f2-b540-c03708ddd21b ro    quiet splash      $vt_handoff
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
```

Перерыла весь гугл, но ничего не нашла, помогите!

Comment: А почему бы просто не удалить все и не поставить Windows?

Comment: Если сбросить пароль - `ro` в твоём прмере поменяй на `rw`. Если удалить и поставить виндуз - согласен с @Axenow. Просто сделай это.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432487/178576

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы попасть в single user mode через grub, нужно к строке:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=uuid=ebed8de5-5b3c-42f2-b540-c03708ddd21b ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
```

дописать `single`
чтобы в итоге получилось:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=uuid=ebed8de5-5b3c-42f2-b540-c03708ddd21b ro quiet splash single $vt_handoff
```

Затем нажать Ctrl+X или F10 чтобы загрузиться в систему с этой опцией.